# v-calendar datepicker stop date from being deselected

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Once a date has been selected, is there a way to stop the date being deselected if the same date is clicked again?  I thought by setting the date in the day clicked event it would stop the deselection, but it doesn't - is there a way to do so?

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      date: new Date(),
      masks: {
        input: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
      },
    };
  },
  methods: {
    dayClicked(day) {
      this.date = new Date(day.id);
    },
  },
});
```

```css
@import url 'https://unpkg.com/v-calendar@2.3.4/lib/v-calendar.min.css';
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/v-calendar@2.3.4/lib/v-calendar.umd.min.js"></script>
<div id='app'>
  <v-date-picker v-model="date" color="orange" :masks="masks" :disabled-dates="{ weekdays: [1, 7] }" @dayclick="dayClicked">
    <template #default="{ inputValue, togglePopover }">
        <label class="form__label date-selector__label" @click="togglePopover">
          <span class="form__label-text date-selector__label-text">Date</span>
          <span class="date-selector__label-value">{{ inputValue }}</span>
        </label>
      </template>
  </v-date-picker>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry I do not understand the question ... what exactly is wrong? can you please elaborate? what do you mean by deselected? Do you want to keep on adding the dates in an array?

Comment: If you click on a date in selects the date, if you click on the same date again, it removes the date - I want it to stop it from removing the date

Comment: Did you try doing a check before assigning the values? 
`dayClicked(day) {
     if (this.date !== new Date(day.id)) this.date = new Date(day.id);
 },`

Comment: @power unfortunately that doesn't work - you can still deselect the date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out there is an `:is-required` attribute you can set to true if you don't want the date to be cleared:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      date: new Date(),
      masks: {
        input: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
      },
    };
  },
  methods: {
    dayClicked(day) {
      this.date = new Date(day.id);
    },
  },
});
```

```css
@import url 'https://unpkg.com/v-calendar@2.3.4/lib/v-calendar.min.css';
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/v-calendar@2.3.4/lib/v-calendar.umd.min.js"></script>
<div id='app'>
  <v-date-picker v-model="date" color="orange" :masks="masks" :disabled-dates="{ weekdays: [1, 7] }" :is-required="true" @dayclick="dayClicked">
    <template #default="{ inputValue, togglePopover }">
        <label class="form__label date-selector__label" @click="togglePopover">
          <span class="form__label-text date-selector__label-text">Date</span>
          <span class="date-selector__label-value">{{ inputValue }}</span>
        </label>
      </template>
  </v-date-picker>
</div>
```